# jQuery UI sortable('cancel') - this.helper is null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to disable a sortable element from sorting when it has been double clicked. When I try to disable it, even without a condition, it gives me the error 'this.helper is null'.

```
$('.roundedBox:first', division).sortable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        if( true === true ) {
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }

        $(this).parent().data( 'sorting', true ); 
    },
    stop: function() { 
        $(this).parent().data( 'sorting', false ); 
    },
    items: '.department',
    update: function() {},
    placeholder: 'department-placeholder'
})
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? I don't need it to be this method. Literally anything thing that stops it will work.

The problem is, sorting starts on a single click, but I have another action bound to double click. If it's double clicked, I don't want it to drag.

---

EDIT

After further investigation sparked by Russ C (thank you), I discovered that the problem is not in the sortable itself, but in combination with two other plugins:

jEditable (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)
jQuery Context Menu (http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/)

The latter is what actually causes the problem. Because the jEditable `h3` tag is within a sortable `div`, which in turn is within a division that has the jQuery Context Menu, which I believe is doing something to stop the propagation (without this last plugin, everything works fine).

To reproduce the problem the following is needed:

HTML

```
<div class="division">
    <div class="roundedBox">
        <div class="department" id="dDeppresident_test">
            <h3>Test</h3>
            <a href="#" title="Menu" class="icon menu hover-icon"><img src="/images/icons/menu-colored.png" alt="Menu" height="15" width="15"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="uDepartmentMenu" class="hidden contextMenu">
    <li><a href="#editDepartment" class="edit" title="Edit Department">Edit Department</a></li>
    <li><a href="#removeDepartment" class="remove" title="Remove Department">Remove Department</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="uDivisionMenu" class="hidden contextMenu">
    <li><a href="#editDivision" class="edit" title="Edit Division">Edit Division</a></li>
    <li><a href="#addDivision" class="add" title="Add Division">Add Division</a></li>
    <li><a href="#removeDivision" class="remove" title="Remove Division">Remove Division</a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="#move" title="Move Division">Move Division</a></li>-->
    <li class="separator"><a href="#addDepartment" class="add" title="Add Department">Add Department</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
// Add context menu to menu icon
$('.division').contextMenu({
    menu: 'uDivisionMenu'
}, function(){} );

// Add Sorting
$('.roundedBox').sortable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        //$(this).parent().data( 'sorting', true ); 
    },
    stop: function() { 
        //$(this).parent().data( 'sorting', false ); 
    },
    items: '.department',
    update: function() {},
    placeholder: 'department-placeholder'
});


// Make the division names editable
$('.department h3').editable( '/ajax/save-department-name.php', {
    indicator   :   'Saving...',
    tooltip     :   'Double click to edit...',
    event       :   'dblclick'
});

// Add context menu to menu icon
$('.department a.menu').contextMenu({
    menu: 'uDepartmentMenu', 
    leftButton: true
}, function(){} );

// Make the departments show remove icon when you hover it
$('.department').live( 'mouseover', function() {
    $( '.hover-icon', $(this) ).show();
}).live( 'mouseout', function() {
    $( '.hover-icon', $(this) ).hide();
});
```

You can see a testing example here (link will be removed at a later date):
http://www.realstatistics.com/testing/

If you remove this section from the jQuery code, all works well:

```
// Add context menu to menu icon
$('.division').contextMenu({
    menu: 'uDivisionMenu'
}, function(){} );
```

I will continue searching for a problem for now.

---

UPDATE

I have fixed this problem. If anyone runs into this issue in the future, I changed the contextMenu plugin to skip its check if the target was on the ".department" class. Right after the "mouseup" function, add a check that checks the event target, like the following:

```
$(this).mouseup( function(e) {
    if( !$(e.target).hasClass('department') && !$(e.target).parent().hasClass('department') ) {
```

Comment: I'm just dealing with this issue, and I worked around it by skipping the evt.stopPropagation in the mousedown handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try adding a delay:500 to the sortable parameters list, perhaps that delay might make the double click bubble properly ?

Similarly, you can use distance:30 which will tell sortable not to start working until the drag has gone on for 30 pixels or more. this can be used to make sure that 'click' events work.

Comment: The double click property is making an editable text field appear. I've tried both delay:500 and distance:30, they are still triggered if the mouse is in the area : \

Comment: Ahh ok; is it possible for you to post some HTML and the double click event ?  I'd like to try and replicate this locally.

Comment: Mm, kind of difficult, I'll see what I can do

Comment: Wow, that lead to a major discovery -- you can see my edit above. I will be accepting your answer soon -- just want to make sure I can actually fix this.

Comment: Additional information: if I can access the division BEFORE the sortable starts, I can probably disable the contextMenu so it won't be a problem, I just don't know of any way I can do that. Is there a way to access the element being clicked?